# Referencing a variable from another method from table value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm need to know how to call/use a string from another method.
I want to transfer data from User table to Employee table. I already setup Foreign key Id From User table to Employee table. but after log in user, they input for their information, so it automatically input Id from User table to Employee table.

[image]

My code is below.

```
public class EmpInputController : Controller
{
    int idd;

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Models.Member model)
    {
        using (var context = new GM_demoEntities())
        {
            bool isValid = context.User.Any(x => x.UserName == model.UserName && x.Password == 
             model.Password);
            var userr = db.User.Where(x => x.UserName == model.UserName && x.Password == 
             model.Password).FirstOrDefault();

            if (userr==null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username and password");
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
            }
            else
            {
                idd = userr.Id; **//I defined this value for moving Id to another table.**

                return RedirectToAction("Empinput", "Empinput");
            }
        }

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Empinput(Employee model)
    {            
        using (var context = new GM_demoEntities())
        {
            Employee Infoma = new Employee();

            Infoma.Id = idd;    **//Defined idd to Employee table.**
            context.Employee.Add(model);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
}
```

That code is not working. `idd` is always 0, so after I input Employee, 0 can only input to Employee table.

[image]

Comment: Tagged as SQL but you've posted C#. You either need to change your tags, or share your SQL so you can get the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with

```
private static int idd;
```

Otherwise you will loose the value from idd when calling the second method, because the value from idd which is set in the first method will be lost.

Anyway, I think you should fetch the id again in the second method. Consider if you are only calling the Empinput() method it could happen to insert an employee with an already existing idd, because the value of idd is not updated by the first method Login().